# Store Procedure is working perfectly fine when executed from front end but is not working when I execute it in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure which works perfectly fine when I execute it from from end i.e.C#.net or when I copy and past the query of stored procedure in separate SQL Query window but it neither give any result nor any error when I execute it in SQL server using EXEC sp_Name. I can not understand what is wrong in my code.

Below is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_tbl_REQUEST_SelectAllByFilter_WithPagging
@PageIndex INT=NULL,
@PageRecord INT=NULL,
@SortExpression NVARCHAR (200)='int_Request_ID',
@SortDirection NVARCHAR (10)='ASC',
@int_Requester_ID INT=NULL,
@intProjectID   INT=NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @StartRowIndex INT
SET @StartRowIndex=((@PageIndex-1)*@PageRecord)+1;

DECLARE @WhrClause VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @WhrClause= 'WHERE  tr.int_Requester_ID = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @int_Requester_ID)
IF(@intProjectID>0)
BEGIN
    SET @WhrClause=@WhrClause+' AND tr.int_Project_ID='+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@intProjectID)
END
DECLARE @SelectClause VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SelectClause=';With AllRecords AS(SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY '+CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), @SortExpression)+' '+CONVERT (VARCHAR (MAX), @SortDirection)+')AS ''RowNumber'',* FROM(SELECT tr.[int_Request_ID],          
        tr.[int_User_ID],          
        tr.[int_Project_ID],          
        tr.[str_Request_Type],          
        tr.[int_Account_ID],          
        tr.[int_Requester_ID],          
        tr.[int_User_Head_ID],          
        tr.[dt_Request_Date],          
        tr.[bln_IsApproved],          
        tr.[dt_Approval_Date],          
        tr.[str_Reject_Reason],          
        tr.[int_USER_ROLE],          
        tr.[int_AllocationType_ID],          
        tr.[int_NoofHourInMinute],         
xyz.dbo.GetHourByMin(ISNULL(int_NoofHourInMinute,0)) as ''str_NoofHour'',           
        tr.[dt_StartDateToWork],
        tr.[dt_EndDateToWork],          
        tr.[isAllowToAddTask],          
        tr.[isAllowToDeleteTask],          
        tr.[isAllowToAddCR],          
        tp.str_Project_Name,          
        tu.str_FullName AS str_User_Name,          
        tu1.str_FullName AS UserHeader,         
        tbl_Project_AllocationType.str_AllocationType,    
        tu2.str_FullName AS UserRequester,  
  tu2.str_EMAIL_ADDRESS as RequesterEmail       
  FROM   [tbl_Requests] tr          
  INNER JOIN tbl_PROJECT tp ON tp.int_Project_ID = tr.int_Project_ID          
  INNER JOIN tbl_USER tu ON tu.int_USER_ID=tr.int_User_ID          
  LEFT JOIN tbl_USER tu1 ON tu1.int_USER_ID=tr.int_User_Head_ID          
  INNER JOIN tbl_USER tu2 ON tu2.int_USER_ID=tr.int_Requester_ID    
inner join tbl_Project_AllocationType on   tbl_Project_AllocationType.int_AllocationType_ID=tr.int_AllocationType_ID '+@WhrClause+'
)As Tmp)

  SELECT * FROM 
 AllRecords WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @StartRowIndex) + ' AND '  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), (@StartRowIndex + @PageRecord - 1)) + '

 SELECT COUNT(TempTbl.int_Request_ID)As  ''ReturnRecords'','+CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@PageIndex)+'''PageIndex''
 FROM (SELECT tr.[int_Request_ID]     
 FROM   [tbl_Requests] tr '+@WhrClause+')as TempTbl;'

PRINT(@SelectClause)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@SelectClause)
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

I am executing it like this.

```
EXEC sp_tbl_REQUEST_SelectAllByFilter_WithPagging 1,20,NULL,NULL,74,591
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `NULL` for `@SortExpression` and `@SortDirection`. `NULL` means that the defaults don't apply - they're null instead.

So the whole concatenation into `@SelectClause` becomes `NULL` (because concatenating strings and `NULL`s produces `NULL`s)

So nothing is executed.

Try:

```
EXEC sp_tbl_REQUEST_SelectAllByFilter_WithPagging
         1,20,@int_Requester_ID = 74,@intProjectID=591
```

Incidentally, you should *avoid* using `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedures. The `sp_` prefix is reserved by MS for system stored procedures, and SQL Server will prefer a system stored procedure from `master` vs your own procedure, if there's a name clash.

(I'd generally recommend against using any prefixes in SQL Server, but that's more of a matter for debate, rather than a strong rule)

Answer (score 1):

Hello You don't need to pass the parameter null

so you can execute store procedure this way

EXEC sp_tbl_REQUEST_SelectAllByFilter_WithPagging 1,20,@int_Requester_ID=74,@intProjectID=591

Try this

Regards
Amit Vyas